# Why does for-loop show nothing in cmd

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have problem with *for loop* in `C#`. 
I have the following code, in main method:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i=0;i>20;i++)
            {
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},", i);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The `for loop` does not execute. Why?

Comment: `i>20` should be `i<20`

Comment: Your condition is `> 20` which is false at the beginning and thus, it does not loop through it.

Comment: note that the condition in a for loop is a "while" condition. the loop will continue "while" the condition remains true.

Answer (score 3):

Change condition, `>` to `<`:

```
 ...
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) // i < 20, not i > 20
 ...
```

In your original code you assign `int i = 0` then check `i > 20` get `false` and *do not enter* the loop at all

Comment: thank you for the help now i need to change i<=20 for include 20.happy christmas.

Comment: @Michael2411: you are welcome! Happy New Year :)

Comment: i just spotted that i wrote happy cristmas instead of Happy new year ;).

Answer (score 1):

The following statement in your code:

> for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)

First assigns `0` to `i` then evaluates the condition `i > 20` which is wrong, so the *for* block can not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have pointed out the fact that the test should actually be "i < 20" rather than "i > 20) but just to make one other point: if all you're trying to do is write out all the even numbers, you can actually increment "i" by 2 every time - that way you never have to test to see if it's even (just write "i += 2" instead of "i++").